# Unable to get ImageView from xml in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have little problem

I write code in java file where under oncreate() method i set the contentview as

```
setContentView(R.layout.main)
```

but under this i need to access a imageview from another xml file name listview

like this

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewbyid(R.id.img)
```

but this img id not present in main.xml it is present in listview.xml then how i can access it.

please give solution ..... thank you

Comment: are you using a custom listview.?

Comment: yes i need to put images in listview from web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inflate the liveview.xml and then find view with inflated layout.

Comment: Idont know how to do that can you explain it little more with code

Comment: LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) ((LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
        .inflate(R.layout.listview, null); and then ImageView img = (ImageView)layout.findViewbyid(R.id.img)